# как получить необходимые данные? python requ

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, requests

```
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict
import json

url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing"

headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
headers["Accept"] = "application/json"
headers["Authorization"] = "key"


resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(resp.content)
data = json.loads(resp.content);
print((data["item"]))
```

получаю

```
{'album': {'album_type': 'single', 'artists': [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/4O15NlyKLIASxsJ0PrXPfz'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/4O15NlyKLIASxsJ0PrXPfz', 'id': '4O15NlyKLIASxsJ0PrXPfz', 'name': 'Lil Uzi Vert', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:4O15NlyKLIASxsJ0PrXPfz'}], 'available_markets': ['AD', 'AE', 'AG', 'AL', 'AM', 'AO', 'AR', 'AT', 'AU', 'AZ', 'BA', 'BB', 'BD', 'BE', 'BF', 'BG', 'BH', 'BI', 'BJ', 'BN', 'BO', 'BR', 'BS', 'BT', 'BW', 'BY', 'BZ', 'CA', 'CD', 'CG', 'CH', 'CI', 'CL', 'CM', 'CO', 'CR', 'CV', 'CW', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DJ', 'DK', 'DM', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'ES', 'FI', 'FJ', 'FM', 'FR', 'GA', 'GB', 'GD', 'GE', 'GH', 'GM', 'GN', 'GQ', 'GR', 'GT', 'GW', 'GY', 'HK', 'HN', 'HR', 'HT', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IN', 'IQ', 'IS', 'IT', 'JM', 'JO', 'JP', 'KE', 'KG', 'KH', 'KI', 'KM', 'KN', 'KR', 'KW', 'KZ', 'LA', 'LB', 'LC', 'LI', 'LK', 'LR', 'LS', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'LY', 'MA', 'MC', 'MD', 'ME', 'MG', 'MH', 'MK', 'ML', 'MN', 'MO', 'MR', 'MT', 'MU', 'MV', 'MW', 'MX', 'MY', 'MZ', 'NA', 'NE', 'NG', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NP', 'NR', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PG', 'PH', 'PK', 'PL', 'PS', 'PT', 'PW', 'PY', 'QA', 'RO', 'RS', 'RW', 'SA', 'SB', 'SC', 'SE', 'SG', 'SI', 'SK', 'SL', 'SM', 'SN', 'SR', 'ST', 'SV', 'SZ', 'TD', 'TG', 'TH', 'TJ', 'TL', 'TN', 'TO', 'TR', 'TT', 'TV', 'TW', 'TZ', 'UA', 'UG', 'US', 'UY', 'UZ', 'VC', 'VE', 'VN', 'VU', 'WS', 'XK', 'ZA', 'ZM', 'ZW'], 'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/64eE6FnNj7UJ9LEkN4EbvS'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/64eE6FnNj7UJ9LEkN4EbvS', 'id': '64eE6FnNj7UJ9LEkN4EbvS', 'images': [{'height': 640, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273099a7b2bba7b013c1292eacf', 'width': 640}, {'height': 300, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e02099a7b2bba7b013c1292eacf', 'width': 300}, {'height': 64, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00004851099a7b2bba7b013c1292eacf', 'width': 64}], 'name': 'New Patek', 'release_date': '2018-09-18', 'release_date_precision': 'day', 'total_tracks': 1, 'type': 'album', 'uri': 'spotify:album:64eE6FnNj7UJ9LEkN4EbvS'}, 'artists': [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/4O15NlyKLIASxsJ0PrXPfz'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/4O15NlyKLIASxsJ0PrXPfz', 'id': '4O15NlyKLIASxsJ0PrXPfz', 'name': 'Lil Uzi Vert', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:4O15NlyKLIASxsJ0PrXPfz'}], 'available_markets': ['AD', 'AE', 'AG', 'AL', 'AM', 'AO', 'AR', 'AT', 'AU', 'AZ', 'BA', 'BB', 'BD', 'BE', 'BF', 'BG', 'BH', 'BI', 'BJ', 'BN', 'BO', 'BR', 'BS', 'BT', 'BW', 'BY', 'BZ', 'CA', 'CD', 'CG', 'CH', 'CI', 'CL', 'CM', 'CO', 'CR', 'CV', 'CW', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DJ', 'DK', 'DM', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'ES', 'FI', 'FJ', 'FM', 'FR', 'GA', 'GB', 'GD', 'GE', 'GH', 'GM', 'GN', 'GQ', 'GR', 'GT', 'GW', 'GY', 'HK', 'HN', 'HR', 'HT', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IN', 'IQ', 'IS', 'IT', 'JM', 'JO', 'JP', 'KE', 'KG', 'KH', 'KI', 'KM', 'KN', 'KR', 'KW', 'KZ', 'LA', 'LB', 'LC', 'LI', 'LK', 'LR', 'LS', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'LY', 'MA', 'MC', 'MD', 'ME', 'MG', 'MH', 'MK', 'ML', 'MN', 'MO', 'MR', 'MT', 'MU', 'MV', 'MW', 'MX', 'MY', 'MZ', 'NA', 'NE', 'NG', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NP', 'NR', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PG', 'PH', 'PK', 'PL', 'PS', 'PT', 'PW', 'PY', 'QA', 'RO', 'RS', 'RW', 'SA', 'SB', 'SC', 'SE', 'SG', 'SI', 'SK', 'SL', 'SM', 'SN', 'SR', 'ST', 'SV', 'SZ', 'TD', 'TG', 'TH', 'TJ', 'TL', 'TN', 'TO', 'TR', 'TT', 'TV', 'TW', 'TZ', 'UA', 'UG', 'US', 'UY', 'UZ', 'VC', 'VE', 'VN', 'VU', 'WS', 'XK', 'ZA', 'ZM', 'ZW'], 'disc_number': 1, 'duration_ms': 343099, 'explicit': True, 'external_ids': {'isrc': 'USAT21811270'}, 'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/track/0Fpen1PTuEnCmOJtUU9Iud'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/0Fpen1PTuEnCmOJtUU9Iud', 'id': '0Fpen1PTuEnCmOJtUU9Iud', 'is_local': False, 'name': 'New Patek', 'popularity': 66, 'preview_url': 'https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/7844815f278bbeede233ce2a906855ce9eda16df?cid=774b29d4f13844c495f206cafdad9c86', 'track_number': 1, 'type': 'track', 'uri': 'spotify:track:0Fpen1PTuEnCmOJtUU9Iud'}
```

нужно получить только

```
https://open.spotify.com/track/0Fpen1PTuEnCmOJtUU9Iud
```

Comment: Да просто напечатайте json с форматированием (отступами) и посмотрите. Там элементарно видно как до нужного значения добраться.

Comment: но каким способом я доберусь до него @insolor

Comment: Ну вот я вставил ваш словарь в файл json, заменил кавычки на двойные и отформатировал файл через vscode: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i3j2.png Очевидно, что к `data["item"]` еще нужно добавить два ключа в квадратных скобках, и вы получите нужное значение.

Comment: я не понимаю как добавить сразу несколько ключей @insolor

Comment: `data["item"]["еще_один_ключ"]["третий_ключ"]`. Первым ключом вы вытащили словарь. Чтобы вытащить значение из словаря - добавляете квадратные скобки с ключом. Внутри оказался еще словарь - добавляете еще один ключ в квадратных скобках. Ничего сложного.

Comment: @insolor, а как открыть  "artists": [
  {
          "external_urls": {
            "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/5NMwoStnfHT4LdETlJSwDT"
          },
      когда открываю artist там скобка

Comment: Квадратные скобки - это список. Доступ к элементу списка делаете через целочисленный индекс.

Comment: @insolor и что я должен сделать что бы получить необходимые мне данные отдельно от всех

Comment: Я думаю, стоит почитать что-нибудь про списки и словари в Python.